# How do I check if my radio button is selected and the loop is working?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, radio-button

So I'm trying to make a quiz.html file which will prompt the user for the no. of questions they want to answer. Based on their input, the random questions will be generated. So I understand it's gonna have to be a loop that will loop till the no. input into the alert box.
So my scoreMe() function apparently isn't giving any answer. I'm trying to check if the checked radio button for a particular question is equal to the correct answer but I'm just getting my score as 0%. So can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
    <div id="quesRes"></div>



<script>

    var quizObj = [
    { 
        "question": "What is the capital of Bangladesh?",
        "choice": ["Dhaka", "Chittagong", "Sylhet"],
        "correct": ["Dhaka"]
   },
   { 
        "question": "What does 2+2 equal to?",
        "choice": ["3", "2", "4"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["4"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the real name of Damon Salvatore?",
        "choice": ["Paul Wesley", "Steven McQueen", "Ian Somerhalder"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Ian Somerhalder"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the name of the largest planet in the universe?",
        "choice": ["Earth", "Jupiter", "Uranus"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Jupiter"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the capital of New York?",
        "choice": ["Manhattan", "NYC", "Albany"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Albany"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "How many bones does the human body have?",
        "choice": ["109", "206", "114"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["206"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the alter ego of Batman?",
        "choice": ["Bruce Banner", "Bruce Wayne", "Tony Stark"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Bruce Wayne"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "How many books are there in the Harry Potter series?",
        "choice": ["7", "5", "8"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["7"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is Naruto's surname?",
        "choice": ["Sarutobi", "Uchiha", "Uzumaki"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Uzumaki"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the name of Sherlock Holmes' partner?",
        "choice": ["Peterson", "Watson", "Hanson"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Watson"]
   },

];

  var track = [];

    var maxQues = prompt("How many questions do you want to answer?", "5");
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxQues);

    var str='<h4>Answer all the questions</h4>';

    for(var i=0;i<maxQues;i++){

        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxQues);
        str+=(i+1)+'.  '+quizObj[rand].question+'<br>';
        str+='<form><table>'+
            '<tr><td id="a1"><input type="radio" id="rad" name="radio' + i + '"/>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[0]+'</td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td id="a2"><input type="radio" id="rad" name="radio' + i + '" />'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[1]+'</td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td id="a3"><input type="radio" id="rad" name="radio' + i + '"/>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[2]+'</td></tr>'+
        '</table></form><br>';
    track[i]=rand;
    }
    str += '<input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="scoreMe()"><br><br>';
    str += 'Score: <input id="score" type="text" size="8" ><br><br><br>';
    document.getElementById('quesRes').innerHTML = str;

  function scoreMe(){
    var sum=0;
    var check=document.getElementById("rad");
    for(var j=0;j<maxQues;j++){
      for(var k=0;k<3;k++){

        if(check.checked===true){
        if(quizObj[track[j]].choice[k]===quizObj[track[j]].correct[0]){
          console.log('Works');
          sum++;
        }
      }

      }
    }
    document.getElementById('score').value = ((sum/maxQues)*100)+'%';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues here.

The first thing I would do is put value attributes on your radio buttons.

Probably something like this.

```
str+='<form><table>'+
        '<tr><td id="a1"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '" value="'+quizObj[rand].choice[0]+'"/>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[0]+'</td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td id="a2"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '" value="'+quizObj[rand].choice[1]+'" />'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[1]+'</td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td id="a3"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '" value="'+quizObj[rand].choice[2]+'"/>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[2]+'</td></tr>'+
    '</table></form><br>';
```

Without value attributes, I'm not sure to what you would compare the correct answer.

Now on to the scoreMe function. You are checking for a checked property on the answer of your quiz object rather than on a DOM element. You need to select the radio elements and check the checked property on those. Something like below:

```
function scoreMe(){
var sum=0;
for(var j=0;j<maxQues;j++){

  var radios = document.getElementsByName('radio' + j),
      rl = radios.length;

  for(var i = 0; i < rl; i++){

    if(radios[i].checked && radios[i].value === quizObj[j].correct[0]){
        sum++;
    }

  }

}
document.getElementById('score').value = ((sum/maxQues)*100)+'%';
  }
```

There remains a logic problem where repeated questions will not score as expected. I would either put in a check to prevent repeated questions at the start or give each question a unique identifier that can be tied to the radio with an html attribute. Then loop the radios and find their question object based on this attribute, rather than looping the question object props first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. And yeah after this was solved, I was gonna look into the randomizer for unique questions

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not really checking what options did the user choose. Your comparison between `quizObj[track[j]].choice[k].checked` and `quizObj[track[j]].correct[0]` isn't comparing what you really want.

`quizObj[track[j]].choice[k].checked` returns `undefined`, because you're trying to get the property `checked` or an element in that array.

For the quiz to work, you need to get the value of the multitple `input` tags, by accessing them, not the array you're accessing. If you remove `.checked` from that `if` clause, you'll be logging what you want to the console. But that check is not what you want to do, if I got it correctly.

Furthermore, you're also outputting `<td>` elements that will have the same `id`, which is unsemantic and will just make things hard for you down the road.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfsp4t8b/) to see it working. Pick only 1 question and look at the console.

Comment: What I want is to find a way to compare if the checked radio button's value matches that of the correct array's value. So i tried something else (edited in the code)and it doesnt work either. Any clues on how to do it?

Comment: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfsp4t8b/1/). Basically, this is working for 1 question. The radios have all the same name, and what you're looking for is their value. If the value of the checked one is the correct answer, score!